# Javascript finding combined properties from an array and object keys

Tags: javascript

I have an object. I would like to be able to dynamically create an array, then create another object that contains the key-value pairs that correspond with  properties from the array that I created.

For example, if I have the following object...

```
var churchMembers = {
  John: 'fsiolfjdklsjds@yahoo.com',
  Betty: 'fowifj@hotmail.com',
  Christopher: 'fsis@yahoo.com',
  James: 'wfowji@gmail.com',
  Deep: 'abab@msn.com'
};
```

and I create the following array:

```
var peopleComing = ['John', 'Christopher', 'James'];
```

I want the following response

```
var peopleList = {
  John: 'fsiolfjdklsjds@yahoo.com',
  Christopher: 'fsis@yahoo.com',
  James: 'wfowji@gmail.com'
};
```

Right now I'm trying to use a `for` loop and all I'm doing is iterating through the object properties, which is not giving me anything.  Going with the `Object.keys` route seems counterproductive, although that would easily allow me to filter out the correct names. Thanks. SIAP

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#forEach` to iterate over your list of names, and get the email for each name and add it to your `peopleList`.

```
var peopleList = {};

peopleComing.forEach(function(name){
    peopleList[name] = churchMembers[name];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the typo you have in your code, the below code should be capable of initializing `peopleList` with what you want.

```
var churchMembers = {
  John: "fsiolfjdklsjds@yahoo.com"
  Betty: "fowifj@hotmail.com",
  Christopher: "fsis@yahoo.com",
  James: "wfowji@gmail.com",
  Deep: "abab@msn.com"
},

peopleComing = ["John", "Christopher", "James"],

peopleList = {};

for (var i = 0, j = peopleComing.length; i < j; i++) {
  peopleList[peopleComing[i]] = churchMembers[peopleComing[i]];
}
```